Thermo Hydraulic Mechanical modeling of energy wall slab in Comsol multiphysics
I am currently working on a complex simulation project involving an energy wall slab, and I need assistance in accurately modeling and validating it using COMSOL Multiphysics. Here are the details of my project:
Geometry and Setup:
Energy Wall Slab Dimensions: Width = 11400 mm, Height = 2000 mm, Thickness = 0.1 m.
Heat Exchangers: Installed within the slab with inlet and outlet positioned at specific heights from each other.
Surrounding Layers: The wall slab is surrounded by soil layers behind and beneath it, and there is an aerogel layer beyond the soil.
Objective:
I aim to create a comprehensive thermo-hydraulic-mechanical model to simulate the behavior of the energy wall slab under various conditions and validate the results with field data. My focus is particularly on the mechanical aspects, such as stress and strain, and ensuring the accuracy of the model.
Issues and Assistance Needed:
Thermo-Hydraulic-Mechanical Coupling:
How to ensure proper coupling between the thermal, hydraulic, and mechanical aspects in COMSOL?
Are there specific settings or steps to follow to accurately simulate thermal expansion and fluid flow interactions?
Stress and Strain Validation:
How can I validate the simulated stress and strain results against field data?
What are the best practices for extracting and comparing simulation data with experimental measurements?
Are there specific postprocessing techniques in COMSOL that can help in this comparison?
Solver Settings and Convergence:
Any recommendations for solver settings to ensure accurate and stable convergence for such a multiphysics problem?
